# PHP - print content from file after manipulation

Tags: php, string, file, compilation, printf

I'm struggling trying to read a php file inside a php and do some manipulation..after that have the content as a string, but when I try to output that with echo or print all the php tags are literally included on the file.

so here is my code:

```
function compilePage($page,$path){
   $contents = array();
   $menu = getMenuFor($page);
   $file = file_get_contents($path);
   array_push($contents,$menu);
   array_push($contents,$file);
   return implode("\n",$contents);
}
```

and this will return a string like

```
<div id="content>
   <h2>Here is my title</h2>
   <p><? echo "my body text"; ?></p>
</div>
```

but this will print exactly the content above not compiling the php on it.

So, how can I render this "compilePage" making sure it returns a compiled php result and not just a plain text?

Thanks in advance

Comment: php.net/variables.scope will tell you that variables defined outside of a function are not available within the function. To access those variables you will need to make use of the `global` statement. You will likely want to consider this templating solution instead: http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function compilePage($page, $path) {
    $contents = getMenuFor($page);
    ob_start();
    include $path;
    $contents .= "\n".ob_get_clean();
    return $contents;
}
```

To evaluate PHP code in a string you use the [eval](http://php.net/eval) function, but this comes *highly* unadvised. If you have a file containing PHP code, you can evaluate it with [include](http://php.net/include), [include_once](http://php.net/include_once), [require](http://php.net/require), or [require_once](http://php.net/require_once) depending on your need. To capture the output of an included file - or required, or whichever method - you need to enable [output buffering](http://php.net/outcontrol).

Comment: thanks erisco, I'm not sure about the other solutions but this appeared to be the simplest one. :) cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) for this, and `include` the file normally:

```
function compilePage($page,$path){
   $contents = array();
   $menu = getMenuFor($page);
   ob_start();
   include $path;
   $file = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
   array_push($contents,$menu);
   array_push($contents,$file);
   return implode("\n",$contents);
}
```

The `include()` call will include the PHP file normally, and `<?php` blocks will be parsed and executed.  Any output will be captured by the buffer created with [ob_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), and you can get it later with the other `ob_*` functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)() so it will execute. You can couple this with [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to get the return in a string.

function compilePage($page,$path){
$contents = array();
$menu = getMenuFor($page);

```
//output buffer
ob_start();
include($path);
$file = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();   

array_push($contents,$menu);
array_push($contents,$file);
return implode("\n",$contents);
```

}